# Chartjs display multiple info with different units in label

Tags: javascript, label, chart.js

I have known that how to show multiple info. with same unit in the label by
**multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabel%> : <%= value %>%"**
and the result as following:
**[]InfoA:50%

[]InfoB:50%**

But I'm now try to show infos with different units such as:
**[]InfoA:50%

[]InfoB:50$**
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Changing Tooltip Template By Label

You can use the `label` property of the valuesObject to figure out the index and use that to pick your symbol, like so

```
Chart.mySymbols = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&'];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(window.data, {
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabel%> : <%= value %><%= Chart.mySymbols[window.data.labels.indexOf(label)] %>"
});
```

Notice that both `data` and `mySymbols` collection are properties of globally referencible objects (`window` and `Chart` in this case, but it could be any global object). This is because only the valuesObject is injected into the `template` function. Unless you want to change the library code, using global objects would be the way to do it (however, do note that its not good design).

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/z1nfqhfn/

---

### Changing Tooltip Template By DataSet

If you want to do a similar thing by dataset, it would be

```
Chart.mySymbols = ['°C', '%'];

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(window.data, {
    multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabel%> : <%= value %><%= Chart.mySymbols[window.data.datasets.map(function(e) { return e.label }).indexOf(datasetLabel)] %>"
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fnu0dyd2/

Comment: In your example, if I want to use different symbols in each label from January to July that use '!' and '@' but not use '!' and '!'. Can I do it?

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite understand that - can you state what symbols you want for each label and I can update the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry about my poor explanation. I have modified from your example at http://jsfiddle.net/h38L9je1/. In this example, there are two line that represent "Temperature" and "Humidity". What I want to do is to add "°C" after the value of temperature and "%" after the value of humidity in each tooltip. How can I do it?

Comment: Hi potatopeelings, I have another question. How can I set different pointDotRadius to these two lines separately?

Comment: You need to extend the chart, and after the prototype initialize, loop through the points and set the `radius` for each point (not pointDotRadius). Cheers!

Comment: Could you supply an example?

Comment: Sure, here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/svw9fehp/ (notice the LineAlt). Btw, for next time, you want to post a separate question to keep things organized - helps other users (comment conversations are not so visible in the search / Google). Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice, I will be more careful next time. You really help me a lot!!!!! :D

Comment: I find something tricky that if I set `animation:false`, the point radius will become to the setting size after mouse hover it.

Comment: Ah! If you are setting animation to false, just do a call to .update() after initializing the chart - see http://jsfiddle.net/ezh4jb3t/